# How to remove part of the middle of a line/string by matching two known patterns in front and behind variable text to be removed

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

How to remove part of the middle of a line/string by matching two known patterns, one in front of text to be removed and one behind the text to be removed?

I have a Linux text file with thousands of one line, comma delimited records. unfortunately, all records are not the same format. Each line may have as many as four comma delimited fields of which only the first and last are constant, the two middle fields may, or may not, be present.

Examples of existing line (record) formats. Messy data but the first field is always present, as is the last field, starts with word ADDED.

```
FNAME LNAME, SOME COMMENT, JOINED DATE, ADDED TO DB DATE

FNAME LNAME, ADDED TO DB DATE

FNAME LNAME, SOME COMMENT, ADDED TO DB DATE

FNAME LNAME, JOINED DATE, ADDED TO DB DATE
```

Objective is to keep field one including the comma, throw away everything following the first comma, keeping the word "ADDED" and everything that follows to the end of line and insert a space between the first comma and the word ADDED.

For each line in parse the file from start of line to the first comma (keep this).

Parse rest of line up to the space before the word “Added” and throw it away.

Keep everything from the space before the word “ADDED” to end of line and concatenate the first part and last part to form one record per line with two fields separated by a comma and a space.

(if record is already in desired format, change nothing)

Final file to look like:

```
FNAME LNAME, ADDED TO DB DATE
```

or

```
Fred Flintstone, ADDED on January 1st 2015 By Barney Rubble
```

Thanks!

Comment: not sure how second output is coming. Could you please put some light on same?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about blank lines:

```
 awk '{print $1,$NF}' FS=, OFS=,  input
```

(Blank lines will be output as a single comma)

If you want to just skip blank lines, use:

```
 awk 'NF>1{print $1,$NF}' FS=, OFS=,  input
```

If you want to keep them:

```
awk '{printf( "%s%s\n", $1, NF>1 ? ","$NF : "")}' FS=, OFS=,  input
```

Note that this will not ensure a single space after the comma, but will retain the spacing as in the final column of the original file.  (that is, if there are 3 spaces after the final column in the original, you'll get 3 in the output).  It's not clear to me from the description, but that seems like desirable behavior.

Comment: Hi, almost there. It outputs the first field correctly up to the comma but only keeps the 4-digit year, not the entire last field.

Comment: What 4 digit year?  Do you have a final column that looks like `Jan 1, 2017`?  If you do, then your final column is just `2017`!

Comment: If you don't have comma delimited data and really just care about the tag 'ADDED', you should probably use `sed 's/,.*ADDED/, ADDED/'`

Comment: This is one of three very different solutions that fails in exactly the same way according to the OP. The most likely explanation is that the data isn't formatted as they claim it is.

Comment: @William Pursell: and Borodin. Yes, the is an extra comma in the data in the "4th field" the is a comma after the date (January 1st, 2016). I will process the file to remove that last comma and retry.  My apologies all.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl solution

```
perl -ne 'print join ", ", (split /,\s*/)[0,-1]' myfile
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/,.*(?=,)//' myfile
```

Both of those solutions work fine for me with the data you have given, but you may like to try

```
perl -pe 's/,.*(?=,\s*ADDED)//' myfile
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Almost there. Both examples output the first field up to the comma correctly, a space, and then the last word of the string which is always a 4 digit year. Like so:  <br/>

Input line- Fred Flintstone, Rock Crusher, Joined Jan 1 2000 BCE, ADDED on January 2 2000 BCE by Barney Rubble  

Desired Output- Fred Flintstone, ADDED on January 2 2000 BCE by Barney Rubble  

Your script output - Fred Flintstone,  2000  
Note in the first script the very last record is output as desired but lacks a newline   
The second script, last record, only outputs the first field.

Comment: @Max:  Both variants work correctly for me, with all the data in your question and with the line in your comment. You have the same problem with two other solutions; perhaps your data isn't as you say it is. Do you have another comma in the data?

Comment: @Max: Yes, please do. It would help a lot if you tested these solutions against the data that you've shown here. If they work with this sample data but not with your live data then you need to ask a new question.

Comment: My initial description is wrong... there is an extra comma after "ADDED" it follows the DAY in the date part of field 4... Like so ___ Fred Flintstone, ADDED on January 1st, 2015 By Barney Rubble. I suspect the last comma is throwing it off. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: After fixing my file and removing the errant comma, both of your first 2 examples worked as expected. Thank you for your help. I agree that data dump is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreference:

```
sed 's/\(^[^,]*,\).* ADDED/\1 ADDED/' file
```

Comment: Hi, this example left all original fields in place.

Comment: The pattern is basic and POSIX compliant. It should just return first field with comma and `ADDED` string with following characters up to the end of line. Default output is terminal. If you want to edit your file in place try the `-i` flag: `sed -i 's/\(^[^,]*,\).* ADDED/\1 ADDED/' file`

Answer (score 0):

one more approach with awk could help here.

```
awk -F, '{val=$1;sub(/FNAME.*\,/,",");print val $0}'   Input_file
```

Where I am making field separator as (,) then saving first field to variable named val, now substituting FNAME till comma with (,) in current line, now printing the value of variable val and new edited current line.

Comment: Hi, this example duplicated the first field, appended it immediately behind the original first field and kept everything else afterwards. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Using perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die "$!: couldn't open file\n";

while(<$fh>) {
    my @arr = split(/,/);
    my $text = $arr[0] . ", " . $arr[$#arr];
    print "$text\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi, almost there. It outputs the first field correctly up to the comma but only keeps the 4-digit year, not the entire last field.

Comment: While I am grateful to see a "proper" program instead of a one-liner, I don't understand going to all that trouble but failing to lay it put nicely. Space characters are free of charge and go a long way towards making your code pleasant to read. Most Perl professionals use [`perldoc perlstyle`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) and it's really not hard.

Comment: @kumar: Thank you, this worked once i cleaned up my input file and removed a comma in the fourth field, thus matching my original post.

Comment: @Borodin i was facing some issues while uploading my answer with proper indentation, so i had to write it this way ...